# Intuit Quickbooks Online API how to handle purchase response in PHP SDK

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to query for purchases from my QBO.

```
    $IPP->version(QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::VERSION_3);

    $PurchaseService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Purchase();

    $purchases = $PurchaseService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Purchase");
    //print_r($purchases);
    foreach($purchases as $purchase){
        //$purchase  how to get the details TxnDate, TotalAmount and other 
line object details  from each purchase object.
    }
```

Please provide me link if there is any doc explaining how to handle the response object  using php. i'm using [IPP V3 Keith Palmer](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3) sdk

There are methods for retrieving information form account query object as show below.

```
$accounts = $AccountService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Account");

    foreach ($accounts as $Account)
    {
        print('Account Id=' . $Account->getId() . ' is named: ' . $Account->getFullyQualifiedName() . '<br>');
        print_r($Account);
    }
```

I'm looking for similar kind of methods to work on purchase response object

I checked the [purchase entities doc](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/purchase) on quickbooks but its not providing details on how to extract data from the response object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP methods *exactly* mirror the XML node names displayed in the Intuit documentation.

For example, Intuit's documentation shows an object like this:

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-04-22T08:58:03.798-07:00">
  <Purchase domain="QBO" sparse="false">
    <Id>603</Id>
    <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
      <CreateTime>2018-07-18T00:00:00-07:00</CreateTime>
      <LastUpdatedTime>2014-04-22T08:57:37-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <TxnDate>2018-07-18</TxnDate>
    <CurrencyRef name="United States Dollar">USD</CurrencyRef>
    <PrivateNote>Taxable expense.</PrivateNote>
    <Line>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Amount>26.00</Amount>
```

So, your Purchase object is going to have methods that mirror this XML structure. For example:

```
$Id = $PurchaseOrder->getId();
$SyncToken = $PurchaseOrder->getSyncToken();

$MetaDataObject = $PurchaseOrder->getMetaData();
$CreateTime = $PurchaseOrder->getMetaData()->getCreateTime();

$TxnDate = $PurchaseOrder->getTxnDate();
```

Unsurprisingly, there are also `->set*(...)` methods too.

```
$PurchaseOrder->setTxnDate('2014-04-24');
```

In the case of line items (which there can be more than one of), you can count the number of `Line` nodes like this:

```
$number_of_lines = $PurchaseOrder->countLine();
```

And then loop through them:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_lines; $i++)
{
  $Line = $PurchaseOrder->getLine($i);
  print_r($Line);
}
```

Unsurprisingly, the Line object will have a method for each node it contains too:

```
$line_Id = $Line->getId();
$line_Amount = $Line->getAmount();
```

As a shortcut, you can also use XPath statements to get at this data:

```
$CreateTime = $Purchase->getXPath('//Purchase/MetaData/CreateTime');
```